# Index by Rowid issue

Tags: sql, database, oracle, indexing, database-performance

Is the plan looking normal? the  `INDEX RANGE SCAN MTL_ITEM_CATEGORIES_N4` is reading 769549 rows and then same number of rows is getting read from the table. Is this normal?

```
         0          0          0             HASH JOIN  (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=19 us cost=181693 size=1530 card=15)
   1146877    1146877    1146877              NESTED LOOPS  (cr=3545011 pr=167590 pw=0 time=3850324669 us cost=181689 size=1005 card=15)
   1146878    1146878    1146878               NESTED LOOPS  (cr=1888277 pr=14528 pw=0 time=1674644783 us cost=181689 size=1005 card=1255314)
    769549     769549     769549                TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED MTL_ITEM_CATEGORIES (cr=51305 pr=7253 pw=0 time=56155426 us cost=6029 size=607410 card=40494)
    769549     769549     769549                 INDEX RANGE SCAN MTL_ITEM_CATEGORIES_N4 (cr=2441 pr=809 pw=0 time=8372404 us cost=190 size=0 card=40494)(object id 24699978)
   1146878    1146878    1146878                INDEX RANGE SCAN MTL_MATERIAL_TRANSACTIONS_N1 (cr=1836972 pr=7275 pw=0 time=323445690 us cost=3 size=0 card=31)(object id 1215228)
   1146877    1146877    1146877               TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID MTL_MATERIAL_TRANSACTIONS (cr=1656734 pr=153062 pw=0 time=2130656126 us cost=30 size=52 card=1)
         0          0          0              TABLE ACCESS FULL MTL_TRANSACTION_TYPES (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us cost=4 size=4095 card=117)
         0          0          0             TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED CST_AE_HEADERS (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us cost=3 size=30 card=1)
```

Comment: "TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED MTL_ITEM_CATEGORIES" is the main process where "INDEX RANGE SCAN MTL_ITEM_CATEGORIES_N4" is within the main process. Suppose index is not there in that case "INDEX RANGE will be not there".

Comment: It is reading same number for rows from table even after reading indexex. is it normal? is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, its normal. In reality "TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED MTL_ITEM_CATEGORIES" is not doing anything it is just an summary of "INDEX SCAN" performed by child process.

Comment: You might want to try using a more readable tool, or at least format it with tkprof.

Comment: SQL Monitor is your friend.